# How to integrate apis in adminLTE in Node.js

Tags: node.js, adminlte

I had successfully installed and and run admin-lte in my Node.js project. As we know they are providing us login, register and forgot password pages for ready to use.

So if I want to make an API (and that API is also made in Node.js) call on one of the page then what steps should I follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should render html page in nodejs (for example inside express.js) and in express.js you can use template engine like: [EJS](https://github.com/tj/ejs) - [hbs](https://github.com/pillarjs/hbs) ... see this [Link](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html).

And for use API inside adminLTE you should use front end web frameworks like: [reactjs](https://reactjs.org/) - [angular](https://angular.io/) - [vuejs](https://vuejs.org/) or use old [jquery](https://jquery.com/) and etc. You can even render static web page and send data into template engine via Expressjs template engine, I explained above.

ReactJS version of the original AdminLTE dashboard: https://github.com/booleanhunter/ReactJS-AdminLTE

AdminLte for Angular 2: 
https://github.com/mledour/angular-admin-lte

See this example for load static web page with hbs:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
//Loads the handlebars module
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
//Sets our app to use the handlebars engine
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
//Sets handlebars configurations (we will go through them later on)
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({
layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts',
}));
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
//Serves the body of the page aka "main.handlebars" to the container //aka "index.handlebars"
res.render('main', {layout : 'index'});
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening to port ${port}`));
```

Comment: thank you for your quick answer.. Did you created public, views and layout folder by your own in node project?

Comment: see this example:1) https://github.com/rahulshukla-rs/node-express-adminlte  2) https://github.com/MuhammadFariMadyan/adminlte-ejs-express 3) https://github.com/RamEduard/admin-lte-express

Comment: yes you shoud create this folder: plz read this https://medium.com/@paulelis/node-express-js-hbs-and-partials-4afa3b16a291

Comment: Links you shared me those are working. But my installed admin-lte version is latest. And when I try to put there admin-lte's code into my ejs file. there css and js is not applying.. Any idea regarding this? with latest version?

Comment: set manually your path js and css file on your source code, or if you want, you can email your source code zip file to me and i can solve your problem.

Comment: I set manually but did not work.. and you email id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214158/discussion-between-taher-fattahi-and-jayna-tanawala).

Comment: thank you for your answer. This helped me -> github.com/MuhammadFariMadyan/adminlte-ejs-express